# Hibernate/PostgreSQL JPAQueryException when trying to use GROUP BY

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, heroku, playframework, hql

I'm getting the following Exception using Hibernate:

> > JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query select f from Flyer as f join f.events as e where e.start > ? and e.start < ? and f.popularityTag > 1 group by f order by sqrt((-118.39419-f.venue.lng) * (-118.39419-f.venue.lng)+(34.024353-f.venue.lat)*(34.024353-f.venue.lat)) asc: ERROR: column "venue2_.lng" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The above shows the HQL for the query. The SQL that that HQL generates is as follows:

> > select flyer0_.id as id345_, flyer0_.venue_id as venue77_345_ from flyer flyer0_ inner join event events1_ on flyer0_.id=events1_.flyer_id cross join venue venue2_ where flyer0_.venue_id=venue2_.id and events1_.start>? and events1_.start1 group by flyer0_.id order by sqrt((-118.39419-venue2_.lng)*(-118.39419-venue2_.lng)+(34.024353-venue2_.lat)*(34.024353-venue2_.lat)) asc limit ?

The Tables are Flyer, Event, and Venue.

The Event table keeps track of the start and stop time of the Flyer... with a Flyer being able to be repeated on multiple days... thus having multiple events.

Each Flyer has a single Venue, where what is advertised on the Flyer will take place.

In terms of my database, I'm using Heroku PostgreSQL Crane, as described in the following URLs. I believe it uses PostgreSQL 9.1:

- https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/5/3/crane_the_new_50_per_month_production_database_/
- https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

In terms of hibernate, Play Framework 1.2.5 which I'm using seems to use:

```
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.10.Final
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-validator 4.1.0.Final
```

MY QUESTION is what is causing that JPAQueryException, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work in PostgreSQL 9.2 due to changes in how GROUP BY clauses including primary keys are handled. In prior versions maybe you can list all columns in the SELECT list in GROUP BY as well, or convince Hibernate to? What Pg version? Hibernate version?

Comment: I'm using Heroku Postgres Crane. I guess it says here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) that they use PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: In terms of Hibernate, I'm using Play Framework 1.2.5, which uses the following: hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final, hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final, hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.10.Final, hibernate-validator 4.1.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that in Pg 9.1 and below you must list all columns in ORDER BY that appear in SELECT, unless they're used in an aggregate. 9.2 and above can figure out that if the PRIMARY KEY is listed in the GROUP BY, then everything else is implicitly grouped too.

It looks like you can re-phrase the query to work around the issue by incorporating a subquery:

```
select f
from Flyer as f
where exists (
  SELECT 1 FROM f.events as e
  where e.start > ? and e.start < ? and f.popularityTag > 1
)
order by sqrt((-118.39419-f.venue.lng) * (-118.39419-f.venue.lng)+(34.024353-f.venue.lat)*(34.024353-f.venue.lat)) asc
```

I haven't tested that and I don't write HQL much, so you might need to tweak it, but the idea should carry through.

Comment: Using the hibernate as you provide, the query appears to run through without error. I notice now though that it seems to take considerably longer to execute that the original query I provided, but lets say if i removed the group by in it. Does it make sense to you that the query is much slower now or should the speed not be affected?

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope It shouldn't make much difference to performance, it's just a workaround for Hibernate's query generation. I'd expect to get much the same query plan. However: how can you compare the execution time of a query that doesn't run with one that does? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope In general, you should use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (from PgAdmin-III or `psql`) to run the raw SQL produced by Hibernate and compare the query plans / performance. Alternately, use `auto_explain` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) to capture plans from the Hibernate queries and get them from the PostgreSQL log files. http://explain.depesz.com/ is useful for analyzing plans and for posting links to them.

Comment: sorry about my lack of clarity in my earlier comment. i was trying to say if i run my original query without the "group by f" part of it, it  seems to run much faster. So if the query was: select f from Flyer as f join f.events as e where e.start > ? and e.start < ? and f.popularityTag > 1 order by sqrt((-118.39419-f.venue.lng) * (-118.39419-f.venue.lng)+(34.024353-f.venue.lat)*(34.024353-f.venue.lat)) asc

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope Well, sure, but that's a different query. Maybe you could try "SELECT DISTINCT f" instead of using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I tried to do the Select Distinct, but this gives a new error.             JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query select distinct f from Flyer as f join f.events as e where e.start > ? and e.start < ? and f.popularityTag > 1 order by sqrt((-118.39419-f.venue.lng) * (-118.39419-f.venue.lng)+(34.024353-f.venue.lat)*(34.024353-f.venue.lat)) asc: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list Position: 3183

Comment: so I just tried "select distinct f, sqrt((-118.39419-f.venue.lng) * (-118.39419-f.venue.lng)+(34.024353-f.venue.lat)*(34.024353-f.venue.lat)) as d from Flyer as f join f.events as e where e.start > ? and e.start < ? and f.popularityTag > 1 order by d asc"... however with that query then Hibernate breaks in trying to translate the results back into Flyers. Specifically I get: ClassCastException occured : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.Flyer.

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope *Shrug*. That's Hibernate. You have one formulation that works, at least.